# Universal kriging in R

Tags: r, kriging

I am new to R for GIS and I am trying to get universal kriging working in Autokrige in R but I am running into problems. Ordinary kriging works with my dataset so I think the problem is to do with the predictor grid which is an ASC file. The data I used is here. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lkg8qtp2eowmml8/AABWYWegF-FgsbIT1i-5y6VEa?dl=0

```
library(sp)
xdata <- read.table(file="C:\\Users\\Robert\\Dropbox\\Dplaces.txt",header=TRUE,na.strings = "NA", sep="\t")

p <- xdata                                              
p$g <- p$Asin.gather
coordinates(p) <- ~ x + y

##Set the coordinate system
proj4string(p) <-CRS("+proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=WGS84")                                              

##Load first temperature GeoTiff raser  from worldclim 
library(raster)
f <- "C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\QGIS Database\\bcmidbi_10m\\bcmidbi11.tif"
       r <- raster(f)
bcmidbi11  <- aggregate(r, fact=2)  ## By default aggregates using mean, but    see fun=

##Load second temperature GeoTiff raser from worldclim 
       f <- "C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\QGIS Database\\bcmidbi_10m\\bcmidbi10.tif"
       r <- raster(f)
bcmidbi10  <- aggregate(r, fact=2)  ## By default aggregates using mean, but see fun=

   ##calculate global effective temperature from rasters which is my predicator variable 
x <- bcmidbi11  /100
y <- bcmidbi10  /100
a <-   18*y
b <-   x  
c <-   y-x
d <-   c+8
e <-   a-b
MET_map <-   e-d
MET<-read.asciigrid("org_matter.asc")
proj4string(MET) <-CRS("+proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=WGS84")


ra <- aggregate(MET_map, fact=2)  ## By default aggregates using mean, but see fun=
writeRaster(ra, "C:\\Users\\Robert\\Documents\\outfile.asc", format="ascii")

Error in .startAsciiWriting(x, filename, ...) : 
x has unequal horizontal and vertical resolutions. Such data cannot be stored in arc-ascii format
```

When this I run into some conversion problem. I tried to experimentally continue with the Meuse dataset, using the Meuse 's data set dist to continue.

```
x.range <- as.numeric(c(-169.00, 172.00))  # min/max longitude of the interpolation area
y.range <- as.numeric(c(-53.00, 79.00))  # min/max latitude of the interpolation area
grd <- expand.grid(x = seq(from = x.range[1], to = x.range[2], by = 0.1), y = seq(from = y.range[1], 
to = y.range[2], by = 0.1))  # expand points to grid, from dataframe to spatialpixels

coordinates(grd) = ~x+y        # from dataframe to SpatialGrid

library(automap)
kriging_result = autoKrige(g~dist, p, new_data=grd)

Error in model.frame.default(terms(formula), as(data, "data.frame"), na.action = na.fail): invalid type (S4) for variable 'dist'
```

Have you any idea what the problem is?

I have tried kriding in other packages and I have had similar problems.